# Start node automatically on Windows restart

Tags: go-ethereum, windows

I need to run a private Ethereum network (clique protocol) on Windows server: how to run the *geth* command automatically every time the server starts or when the service goes down?

So far I tried to make a PowerShell script (like the one below) but without success:

```sh
Start-Job { & 'C:\Program Files\Geth\geth.exe' --nousb --datadir="[...]" --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --networkid 5053 --http --http.addr 192.168.0.123 --http.corsdomain '*' --http.port 8545 --http.vhosts '*' --http.api admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 --mine --allow-insecure-unlock --bootnodes '[...]' --ipcdisable }
```

Do you have any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set up the tasks in the Windows Task Scheduler GUI

server start
Begin the task : At startup (might want to build in a bit of a delay)

service goes down
Begin the task : On an event, Log: find the relevant event  --  or could set the service's Recovery params to constantly restart on failures in services.msc

You could set the service Startup Type to Automatic (Delayed Start), but I'm guessing there's a reason you're not doing that already.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Following up your solution, I added a scheduled task with this action `powershell -file "c:\path-to-powershell-script\start.sp1"` and in the script `start.sp1` I placed the *geth* command to start the blockchain node.